# Determining the velocity is terms of displacement given acceleration. (terminology)

Tags: calculus, physics

So I  need to determine the velocity in terms of displacement. It was given the acceleration of the particle is $a(x) = 49x - 14$

I know that $a =  \frac{d}{dx}(\frac{1}{2}v^2)$; which is $49x-14\:=\:\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{2}v^2\right)$

This is where I got bamboozled, my textbook went straight to $\frac{1}{2}v^2=\int \:49x-14\:dx$. How?

I get that you need to times $dx$ by both sides. But Where did the $"d"$ go? So when you integrate both sides, the $"d"$ and the integral sign cancel out?

Like so:
$\int \:\frac{1}{2}v^2\:\:\:d=\int \:49x-14\:dx$

and $"d"$ cancels out?

$\:\frac{1}{2}v^2\:=\int \:49x-14\:dx$

Comment: Think of it as integrating both sides rather than as "times $dx$ by both sides"

Answer (score 1):

In general we have that [**by definition**](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IndefiniteIntegral.html):

$$\frac {dF(x)}{dx}=f(x) \iff F(x)= \int_0^x f(u) du$$

with $F(x)=\frac12 v^2$ and $f(x)=49x-14$ in your case.

We don't cancel out "d" which is just used as a symbol to indicate the derivative or the integrating variable.

Answer (score 0):

Note that

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{2}v^2\right) =49x-14 $$

leads to
$$d\left(\frac{1}{2}v^2\right) =(49x-14)dx $$

Then, integrate both sides

$$\int d\left(\frac{1}{2}v^2\right)= \frac{1}{2}v^2 =\int (49x-14)dx $$